# Terminator Genisys Plot Point?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

The T-800 (sent in 1984) was sent to kill Sarah Connor but it was trying kill Kyle Reese instead.

Why is that?

Did I miss this difference being explained?

Comment: Downvoters care to comment or improve this question?

Comment: There were two T-800 sent back in the past. The original timeline T-800 programmed to kill Sarah Connor, and the older T-800 who protects her from the latter, sent from a further future. I did not see the movie recently but the first minutes of the plot were pretty straightforward for me. But if you never saw any other Terminator film before you could indeed lack some backstory.

Comment: The t-800 (programmed to kill sarah) was trying to kill KYLE REESE (killing kyle reese is not his mission). 

I'm not talking about Pops... I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: My bad. The T-800 real mission is to avoid the birth of John Connor, by killing either his mother... or father, so i guess it makes sense he's trying to kill Reese.

Answer (score 4):

The T-800 sent back in *Genisys* is initially sent to kill Sarah Connor but is **immediately** disabled by Pops and Sarah on arrival at the Observatory.

They load it in their truck/van and take it with them when saving Reese from the T-1000.

As they are attacked in the abandoned factory by the T-1000 (after it tracks them down) the T-1000 drops some of itself (the special metal) onto the T-800 which repairs and **reprograms** the T-800 to attack Reese while it kills Sarah.

A short struggle ensues and Reese blows the T-800's head off.

Comment: I thought that only TX from terminator 3 has the ability to that. Now i'm wondering why didn't the t-1000 used the same technique in terminator 2.

Comment: What would the T-1000 have used this ability on in T2?

Comment: This is a different timeline...you can't apply what happens in Genisys to T2